# how to access different tables in same database in jpa/eclipselink

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I have two entity classes say Class A and B and two corresponding service classes Aservice and Bservice, and here is my persistence.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="adara" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>com.qaf.model.entity.Inwards</class>
    <class>com.qaf.model.entity.Stock</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby:./workshopDB;create=true"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Now when I am doing a `SELECT` query for class A it's giving me the result, But when I am doing `SELECT` query for class B, I am getting an exception like

> [EL Warning]: 2015-03-16 19:40:14.196--UnitOfWork(27187220)
>   Thread(Thread[JavaFX Application Thread,5,main])--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
>
> Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Column 'DESPATCHNO' is either not in any table in the FROM list or appears within a join specification and is outside the scope of the join specification or appears in a HAVING clause and is not in the GROUP BY list. If this is a CREATE or ALTER TABLE  statement then 'DESPATCHNO' is not a column in the target table.
>
> Error Code: 30000

I am a beginner of JPA hope you guys will help me.

Comment: It is difficult to know what the problem would be without seeing the entity classes. At first guess, I'd say that the column name `'DESPATCHNO'` is probably misspelled in your query.

Comment: If your Class B is the Stock class, can you post its source code? And also post your select query expression.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Owen , here column name    DESPATCHNO is not misspelled in my query and B is not the stock class. Here the problem is i think only the entity manager of class A is active, and entity manager of class B is being flushed when A is active. Now can you tell me how to manage the state of entity manager manually.

Comment: I'm not sure what state of the EntityManager you are trying to manage , as this is a table level error which are created up front when the persistence unit is first accessed/deployed.  How are you obtaining your EntityManager instances, and what does it have to do with flushing while class A is active?  Turn on EclipseLink logging to see what statements are being issued to get an idea of why your column might not be there.